# Adding url into <a href=""> with Emmet

Tags: html, emmet

Does Emmet have a syntax for adding a `URL` into `<a href="">`?

E.g.:

Syntax:

```
a:www.google.com
```

Result:

```
<a href="www.google.com"></a>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The general syntax for adding an attribute to an element in Emmet is:

```
element[attr=value]
```

So in this case, it'd be:

```
a[href=www.google.com]
```

That said, if you just do `a` by itself, it should automatically jump the editor cursor into the `href` attribute, and you can do `a:link` to pre-populate it with a `http://`. So those options might be faster/more to your tastes.

For more information, look at the [Emmet Cheat Sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) - it lists all the syntax that's available.

Comment: How would I add the content of the element into the href? For example, 

    `<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>`
    
So when I wrap the link https://google.com it gets place in the href. I know it will do it when using only `a` by itself, but I want to create a custom anchor tag such as:

    `a[href=\"{whatever the value is}\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\"]`

I am wrapping a lot of links and therefore need a way to do this more efficiently. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Slightly shorter:

```
a[www.google.com]
```

equals:

```
<a href="www.google.com"></a>
```

Comment: Can't find the relevant part in [the docs](http://docs.emmet.io/) but it works for me.

Comment: if I emmet add an text, type a, the href is filled out. when I than press enter the href is emptied again.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It results in `<a href="" www.google.com=""></a>`

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode you can wrap the text you need to link and as the link url, use "Wrap with Abbreviation" (Cmd+Shift+P and type Emmet to see shortcuts).

Use this snippet: `a[href="$#"]`
The content will be interpolated as the link URL.

From `http://www.example.com` to `<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>`